# How do find if a relation is a function algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, relations

Is there a way to see if a relation is a function without having to do a "vertical line test" (where you draw a vertical line on the graph and if there line touches two points then it's not a function).

To determine if a function is even or odd you simply go f(x) = f(-x); even, f(-x) = -f(x); odd. Can I do something similar to find out if a relation is a function?

Thanks

Comment: Your example of even and odd functions isn't really an algebraic way of solving.

Comment: Ok, what type of method is it?

Comment: I don't know.  But that's definitely not 'solved' algebraically, I can tell you that much.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Simple Art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a relation to be a function, it must be one-to-one or injective, meaning that it must map each input into a different output.

If you can't use the vertical line test, see if you can determine whether or not the function/relation has branches.

Comment: Ok, can you do that algebraically? Like for even and odd functions I can go; if f(x) = f(-x) it's even and if f(-x) = -f(x). Can I do something similar to see if a relation is a function?

Comment: @frog1944 I would look at what operations are in the function and determine if any of them have branches.  i.e. logs, trig, roots, exponentials, etc.

Comment: Ok, so there is no similar way to find out if it's a function other than looking at the function and determining if it has any branches?

Comment: @frog1944 Well, you can break it up into parts and pieces if that makes it easier.  Also look to see if it is defined for all $x$, else it isn't a relation.  And of course, this depends on if you consider $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or something different.  But no, not that I think.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: @frog1944 My pleasures.